# Array Map in javascript changes all the element in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, dictionary

I have a vector of objects in Javascript (React Native) and I need to add a different random key to each item of the array.
The problem is that if I add the key property to one object it will update the same key to each element of the array.

I don't even know which is the problem.

My original array is:

```
[{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3},{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3}]
```

The result I get is this:

```
Lista prodotti randomico: [{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3,"key":"x4idec"},{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3,"key":"x4idec"}]
```

The problem happens only when the item are the "same".

```
componentWillMount(){

    this.props.productList.map(item => {
      item.key = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
    })

}
```

The expected result is a different key on each object, like this:

```
Lista prodotti randomico: [{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3,"key":"x4idec"},{"nome":"insalata di mare","prezzo":0.3,"qr_code":"qr_valore","quantita":3,"key":"d2jdss"}]
```

Comment: How do you build/create `this.props.productList`. Sounds like your issue is that you have an array of pointers all pointing to the same object

Comment: @Pointy it happens the same also if I reassign the map return to the props.productList

Comment: The callback of `Array.prototype.map()` should return the new value to build a new array. Your script should use `.forEach()` as you're changing the values in the array directly/in-place.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's causing this, but it's a core principle of React that the `props` should be immutable - that is, you shouldn't alter them in-place.

Comment: @xcsob don't mutate your data, especially not the `props` even more especially not, if these prop just contains the same object over and over again `this.mappedproductList = this.props.productList.map(item => ({ ...item, key: Math.random().andSoOn }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that each element of the array is in fact a different object?

If you do something like this:

```
let a = {foo: 'bar'};
let b = a;
let array = [a, b];
```

The `array` will look like this:

`[{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}]`

If you use `map` as you've shown above, both elements will indeed change together, because each element of the array *is the same object*, just the same object appearing at more than one index in the array.

`array.map((item, index) => item.key = index)`

Will result in:

`[{foo: 'bar', key: 1}, {foo: 'bar', key: 1}]`

NOT `[{foo: 'bar', key: 0}, {foo: 'bar', key: 1}]`, like you might have wished.

To be sure each element of the array changes independently, you need to assure that each element is an independent object. Using something like lodash's `clone` function would help.

`array.map((item, index) => _.clone(item).key = index)`

Comment: Good catch, @Nick!

Comment: _"Using something like lodash..."_ - Instead of adding just another library/workaround the correct thing to do would be to fix the source of the problem.

Comment: @Andreas, I don't disagree, lodash's `clone` was simply an easy way to demonstrate the concept, without having access to whatever code might be behind the scenes.

Comment: You are right, I didn't used the clone in my redux store. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what @kshetline wrote.

I believe this should be what you want without the use of an external library.

```
const products = this.props.productsList.map((product, key) => ({
  ...product,
  key
}));
```

The key take away here is that a new object will be created, however if you have a key property it will be overridden!

Let me know what you think!